# how to prove that $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \ln\left(\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}\right) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can i see that beacuse the logarithm is strictly increasing and not bounded and the input $\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}$ converges to $\infty$, $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \ln \frac{j^2+1}{j+1} = \infty$ ??

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The question is probably to show that the limit tends to infinity.

Comment: @BenjaminWang you were right!

Comment: $\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}>j-1$

Answer (score 5):

For a really simple proof, @saulspatz gave you a nice little observation. We have
$$
j^2 + 1 > j^2 - 1
$$
and so
$$
\frac{j^2 + 1}{j+1} > \frac{j^2-1}{j+1} = \frac{(j+1)(j-1)}{(j+1)} = j-1
$$
so
$$
\frac{j^2+1}{j+1} > j-1
$$
since ${\log}$ is increasing, we have
$$
\log\left(\frac{j^2+1}{j+1}\right) \geq \log\left(j-1\right)
$$
can you finish it from here?

If you can't:

> We know $\log$ is unbounded, i.e. ${\lim_{j\to\infty}\log(j)=\infty}$. This means that for any ${R>0}$, we can find a corresponding ${j^*}$ such that ${\log(j^*)>R}$. We can do the same with ${\log(j-1)}$, just choose ${(j^* + 1)}$. This shows ${\log(j-1)\to \infty}$, and since the original expression ${\log\left(\frac{j^2 + 1}{j+1}\right)}$ is greater than this, it too must go to infinity.

Comment: (+1) for your systematic approach, the last theorem is known well when we talk about sequences, if $\lim u_n =+\infty$ and $v_n>u_n$ hence $\lim v_n =\infty$. We call it in french `Théorème d'ordre`

Answer (score 1):

$\ln$ being unbounded means that for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$ we can find $x_M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\ln(x_M)>M$. Being increasing implies on the previous that for every $x\geq x_M$, $\ln(x)\geq\ln(x_M)>M$.

Plug your sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left(\dfrac{n^2+1}{n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and pick $M\in\mathbb{R}$. You know that $x_n\to\infty$, so there exists $n(M)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n>x_M$ for all $n\geq n(M)$. This means that $\ln(x_n)\geq\ln(x_M)>M$, which is exactly the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(x_n)$ being infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

$$\frac{j^2 +1}{j+1} \enspace = \enspace \frac{j + \tfrac{1}{j}}{1 + \tfrac{1}{j}}$$

And therefore

$$\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln \Big( \frac{j + \tfrac{1}{j}}{1 + \tfrac{1}{j}} \Big) \enspace = \enspace \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln \Big( j + \tfrac{1}{j} \Big) - \underbrace{\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln \Big( 1 + \tfrac{1}{j} \Big)}_{= 0} \\ = \enspace \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln \Big(j + \tfrac{1}{j} \Big)  \\ = \enspace \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln j (1+\tfrac{1}{j^2}) \\ = \enspace  \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln j + \underbrace{\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln(1+\tfrac{1}{j^2})}_{=0} \\ = \enspace \lim_{j\rightarrow \infty} \ln j \\ = \enspace \infty$$

You would still have to show that it is strictly increasing and not bounded though.

EDIT: Thanks to J.G. for contributing within the last steps.

Comment: Hmm... how do we know ${\lim_{j\to \infty}\log\left(j + \frac{1}{j}\right)}$ is the same as ${\lim_{j\to\infty}\log(j)}$?

Comment: Perhaps using the fact that ${\log}$ is increasing, we can instead say ${\log\left(j + \frac{1}{j}\right) > \log(j)}$ instead and use this to argue the limit is also infinity?

Comment: Or use $j+\tfrac1j=j\left(1+\tfrac{1}{j^2}\right)$.